# Drag'n'drop в Delphi

Tags: drag-n-drop, delphi

Всем доброго времени суток!

Сегодня делал лабораторную по теме "Drag'n'drop-интерфейс в Delphi". Про интерфейс этот почитал, в-принципе, вроде бы все понял как делать. Теперь застрял на связке ListBox <=> RadioGroup. Не могу никак побороть исключение при перетаскивании RadioButton **в** ListBox. Причем это исключение появляется уже ПОСЛЕ **удаления** RadioButton из RadioGroup (после выполнения всего кода). Можно даже сделать Form.Refresh и на форме все отрисуется правильно. Ко всему прочему, исключение генерируется только при перетаскивании последнего RadioButton из RadioGroup, добавленного **при создании формы** (т.е. грубо говоря, последней строки, которую я прописал в RadioGroup.Items) и еще в некоторых случаях (пока что сам не пойму в каких). Какой-то логики в этом я не вижу, поэтому и обращаюсь к вам за помощью.

Вот часть кода:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  RG: TRadioGroup;
  RB: TRadioButton;
  LB: TListBox;
implementation
...

procedure TForm1.lst1DragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
  State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  if (Source is TRadioButton) and (TRadioButton(Source).GetParentComponent is TRadioGroup) then
    Accept := True
  else
    Accept := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.lst1DragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
var sep: TListBox;
begin
  sep := TListBox(Sender);
  if (Source is TRadioButton) and (TRadioButton(Source).GetParentComponent is TRadioGroup) then begin
    RB := TRadioButton(Source);
    RG := TRadioGroup(TRadioButton(Source).GetParentComponent);
    sep.Items.Add(RB.Caption);
//    ShowMessage(IntToStr(RG.Items.IndexOf(RB.Caption)));
    RG.Items.Delete(RG.Items.IndexOf(RB.Caption));
    Form1.Refresh;

//В дебагере видно что после выполнения данного события происходит исключение, но если убрать строку RG.Items.Delete(RG.Items.IndexOf(RB.Caption)); то все работает нормально

  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.rg1RadioItemMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  TRadioButton(Sender).BeginDrag(false, 5);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to rg1.Items.Count - 1 do begin
    rg1.Buttons[i].OnDragOver := rg1DragOver;
    rg1.Buttons[i].OnDragDrop := rg1RadioItemDragDrop;
    rg1.Buttons[i].OnMouseDown := rg1RadioItemMouseDown;
  end;
end;
```

Версия Delphi: Lite Edition 7.3 (неоффициальная). Операционка: Windows 7

[Вот тут](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B0KOKNKlYmTTeFRNMGdQeEMwTTQ&export=download) выложил весь проект целиком. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Какой тип исключения и что в сообщении?

Comment: В D7 ошибок нет.

Comment: @KiTE, исключение - EAccessViolation. Ну и далее текст стандартный: "Access violation at adress \* in module '\*.exe'. Read of address *"

Comment: @Dobby007, это исключение обращения к памяти. Вы пытаетесь прочитать пустой участок. Код не читал (лень), так что скорее всего вы пытаетесь выполнить какие-то действия над несуществующим объектом. Посмотрите, какие объекты вы удаляете, как вы их удаляете, и не делаете ли вы с ними что-то после их удаления.

Comment: @teanЫЧ, в том то и дело что я ничего не делаю. Исключение возникает уже после выполнения моего кода (даже после обновления формы). Причем мой код отрабатывает правильно.

Comment: @Dobby007, скачал архив, распаковал, запустил в дебагере - ошибки нет. Delphi XE2 Pro

Comment: @teanЫЧ, ну я так и подумал, что че-то моя delphi мне походу мозги парит. А Вы как проверяли? Просто я было тоже запустил и подумал, что все работает. Ошибка появляется, когда запускаешь и сразу, ничего больше не делая, перетаскиваешь **последний** пункт из radiogroup. У вас такого нет? И еще вопрос: сам RadioButton удаляется?

Comment: @Dobby007, Да, пробовал сразу удалить последний пункт - все нормально, и radiobutton удаляется.

Comment: @teanЫЧ, спасибо большое. Тогда вопрос закрыт.